# How to have Native picture size with InitialMag's fit in Matlab's imagesc?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am converting all my Matlab codes of Matlab 2016a from OS X El Capitan environment to Debian/Ubuntu environent. The following code works in the former but not in the latter. I would like to understand how to use `InitialMag` as `fit` in `imagesc`. I want to have the native picture size. 
Code

```
clear all; close all;
aFig = figure('Name','Monitoring'); 
a1=subplot(2,1,1, 'Parent', aFig);
a2=subplot(2,1,2, 'Parent', aFig);

bFig = figure('Name', 'Data');
hax=axes(bFig);

[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25); surf(X,Y,Z);
colormap(hax, 'hot');
set(hax, 'XTickLabelMode', 'manual', 'XTickLabel', []); 
set(hax, 'YTickLabelMode', 'manual', 'YTickLabel', []); 
axis off; % no ticks

[I,alpha]=export_fig('/home/masi/Desktop/test', '-png',hax);

imagesc(a1, I, 'InitialMag', 'fit');
```

Output

```
Error using image
There is no InitialMag property on the Image class.

Error in imagesc (line 39)
    hh = image(varargin{:},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Error in test_parent_property (line 17)
imagesc(a1, I, 'InitialMag', 'fit');
```

If you change the last line to `imagesc(a1, I, 'InitialMag', 'fit');`, no such error.

Matlab: 2016a
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: you wrote: *"If you change the last line to:* `imagesc(a1, I, 'InitialMag', 'fit');` , *no such error."* Isn't this already your last line? What change are you doing?

Comment: is [**`truesize`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/truesize.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Can you please give some code examples. I cannot get your proposal work. I will try it later too in Matlab 2016b prerelease.

Comment: Just run `truesize` after your call to `imagesc`. That's it.  *Puts on my special Masi mileage goggles*. Here we go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sardar's answer confirmed by rayryeng

```
imagesc(time,potential,C); 
truesize
```